# How to expand a <div> horizontally to 100% width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to be able to expand a div on click in order to make the div occupy 100% of the width. Right now, there are two videos playing side by side, and when one is clicked, I would like for it to expand to full width and minimize the other video. Here is my code, I cannot understand why this simple javascript does not do the trick:

```js
function expandRight() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('.left').setAttribute("style","width:100%");
    document.getElementsByClassName('.left').style.width='100%';
}
```

```css
.full-width{
        width: 100%;
    }

    .flex{
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
    }

    .nav{
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    }

    .header__menu{
        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
    }

    .nav__video{
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .left, .right {
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    }

    .nav__video--left, .nav__video--right{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    video{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

```html
  <nav>
            <div class="nav flex full-width">
                <div class="nav__video flex full-width">
                    <div class="left">
                        <div class="nav__video--left" onclick="expandRight()">
                            <video playsinline autoplay muted loop>
                            <!--- Inlcude the video files with .webm file first --->
                                <source src="assets/videoLeft/loop.webm">
                                <source src="assets/videoLeft/loop.mp4">
                                <source src="assets/videoLeft/loop.mov">
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <div class="nav__video--right" onclick="expandLeft()">
                            <video playsinline autoplay muted loop>
                            <!--- Inlcude the video files with .webm file first --->
                                <source src="assets/videoRight/loop.webm">
                                <source src="assets/videoRight/loop.mp4">
                                <source src="assets/videoRight/loop.mov">
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Any help here is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: http://codepen.io/SpencerMiller23/pen/YprgMj Here is a codepen I created that does a similar function, and works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make sure you have a correct HTML structure and CSS classes.

```js
var div1 = document.getElementById("left");
var div2 = document.getElementById("right");
var reset = document.getElementById("reset");

div1.addEventListener("click", function(e){ 
  growShrink(this, div2); 
});

div2.addEventListener("click", function(e){ 
  growShrink(this, div1); 
});

reset.addEventListener("click", function(e){
 growShrink(null, null, true);
});


function growShrink(g, s, r){
  if(r){
      div1.setAttribute("class", "content"); 
      div2.setAttribute("class", "content");
      return;
  }
  g.setAttribute("class", "expanded");
  s.setAttribute("class", "shrunk");
}
```

```css
#wrapper { padding:0; }
div { border: 1px dashed black; }
.content { 
  width:49.5%; float:left; margin:0; 
}

}
.expanded { width:100%; }
.shrunk { display:none;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  
  <div id="left" class="content">L E F T</div>
  <div id="right" class="content">R I G H T</div>
  
</div>

<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: @SpencerM. You're welcome. I just added a reset button as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:**

There are a couple of issues to fix in your javascript:

```
function expandRight() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('.left').setAttribute("style","width:100%");
    document.getElementsByClassName('.left').style.width='100%';
}
```

**1)** As you probably realise, you don't need both of these statements, because they both do the same thing, which takes us to...

```
function expandRight() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('.left').style.width='100%';
}
```

**2)** But the class name in question *isn't* `.left`, it's `left`, which takes us to...

```
function expandRight() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('left').style.width='100%';
}
```

**3)** When you use `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementsByTagName`, you are collecting the entire nodelist. So if you want just one item within that nodelist, you have to explicitly state the index of that nodelist item.

In this case, there is only one element with the class name `left`, so the element is the first item in the nodelist, ie. `document.getElementsByClassName('left')[0]`.

You'll see that (apart from all the other things you need to fix),

```
function expandRight() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('left')[0].style.width='100%';
}
```

now works.

---

**Slightly Longer Answer**

If you take the steps above into account and then ensure that while the function increases the width of one div to 100%, it simultaneously decreases the width of the other div to 0, you'll end up with something like the following:

```js
var leftBox = document.getElementsByClassName('left')[0];
var rightBox = document.getElementsByClassName('right')[0];

function expandLeft() {
    rightBox.style.width='100%';
    leftBox.style.width='0';
}

function expandRight() {
    leftBox.style.width='100%';
    rightBox.style.width='0';
}
```

```css
.full-width{
        width: 100%;
    }

    .flex{
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
    }

    .nav{
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    }

    .header__menu{
        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
    }

    .nav__video{
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .left, .right {
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    }

    .nav__video--left, .nav__video--right{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    video{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

```html
       <nav>
            <div class="nav flex full-width">
                <div class="nav__video flex full-width">
                    <div class="left">
                        <div class="nav__video--left" onclick="expandRight()">
                            <video playsinline autoplay muted loop>
                            <!-- Inlcude the video files with .webm file first -->
                                <source src="assets/videoLeft/loop.webm">
                                <source src="assets/videoLeft/loop.mp4">
                                <source src="assets/videoLeft/loop.mov">
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <div class="nav__video--right" onclick="expandLeft()">
                            <video playsinline autoplay muted loop>
                            <!-- Inlcude the video files with .webm file first -->
                                <source src="assets/videoRight/loop.webm">
                                <source src="assets/videoRight/loop.mp4">
                                <source src="assets/videoRight/loop.mov">
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you man, I read in another post that you should include both of those statements that change the width for cross-browser support. Is that not true? @rounin

Comment: That was good advice a few years ago. In 2016 you can be pretty confident that 99.9% of browsers in use will support `.style.width`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jquery to Animate these two videos, it looks really nice and is pretty simple.

I created a little example real quick, using `.animate`, check out the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SchnetzApps/x75cnLvw/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of KenSchnetz's script in vanilla JS in case anyone else reading this just needs to stick with just that (you can find a link to the updated JSFiddle at the bottom):

```
    var screenWidth = window.innerWidth,

    videoA = document.getElementById('a'),

    videoB = document.getElementById('b');



    function toggleSize(video, moveLeftOnExpand, z, w, h, l) {

        if (!moveLeftOnExpand) {

            video.style.zIndex = z;

            video.style.width = w;

            video.style.height = h;

        } else {

            video.style.zIndex = z;

            video.style.width = w;

            video.style.height = h;

            video.style.left = l;

        }


    } 


    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        switch(e.target) {

            case videoA: 

                if (videoA.clientWidth < screenWidth) {

                    toggleSize(videoA, false, 2, '100%', '80vh');

                } else {

                    toggleSize(videoA, false, 1, '50%', '50vh');

                }

            break;

            case videoB: 

                if (videoB.clientWidth < screenWidth) {

                    toggleSize(videoB, true, 2, '100%', '80vh', 0);

                } else {

                    toggleSize(videoB, true, 1, '50%', '50vh', '50%');

                }

            break;

        }

    }, false);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/maxioso7/58w9tb3c/